# Scrapy extract URL (href) element without tags

Tags: python, scrapy

I have managed to extract some data with the following program. However, when I check over the extract data result, I realise I could not grab the href element (the url) included in the 'question_content' if there is url inside the content.

```
import scrapy

class JPItem(scrapy.Item):
    best_answer = scrapy.Field()
    question_content = scrapy.Field()
    question_title = scrapy.Field()

class JPSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "jp"
    allowed_domains = ['detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp']

    start_urls = [
        'https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q' + str(x)
        for x in range (12174460000,12174470000)
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = JPItem()

        item['question_title'] = response.css("div.mdPstd.mdPstdQstn.sttsRslvd.clrfx div.ttl h1::text").extract_first()
        item['question_content'] = ''.join([i for i in response.css("div.mdPstd.mdPstdQstn.sttsRslvd.clrfx div.ptsQes p::text").extract()])
        item['best_answer'] = ''.join([i for i in response.css("div.mdPstd.mdPstdBA.othrAns.clrfx div.ptsQes p.queTxt::text").extract()])

        yield item
```

**EDIT 1**
[image: Question_content that would like to grab]

As seen from the picture, there is a url which I am not able to catch it in the "::text" format, but if omitting the "::text", will get other unrelated data and tags like, i.e. br, p.

**How can I do to just also grab that link while not including the br and p tag?**

Comment: Please show the HTML of the element you are trying to scrape and what attribute in particular you want to extract

Comment: @lufte I have included a picture to show the element that I would like to grab. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this new code:

```
import scrapy
import re

class JPItem(scrapy.Item):
    best_answer = scrapy.Field()
    question_content = scrapy.Field()
    question_title = scrapy.Field()
    question_link = scrapy.Field()

class JPSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "jp"
    allowed_domains = ['detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp']

    start_urls = [
        'https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12174467757?__ysp=VVNC',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = JPItem()

        item['question_title'] = response.css("div.mdPstd.mdPstdQstn.sttsRslvd.clrfx div.ttl h1::text").extract_first()
        item['question_content'] = re.sub('[\s+]', '', ''.join([i for i in response.css("div.mdPstd.mdPstdQstn.sttsRslvd.clrfx div.ptsQes p::text").extract()]))
        item['question_link'] = ''.join(response.css("div.mdPstd.mdPstdQstn.sttsRslvd.clrfx div.ptsQes p:not([class]) a::text").extract())
        item['best_answer'] = re.sub('[\s+]', '', ''.join([i for i in response.css("div.mdPstd.mdPstdBA.othrAns.clrfx div.ptsQes p.queTxt::text").extract()]))

        yield item
```

The the output can give you:

```
'question_content':'USBについての質問です下記のサイトの通りCentOS7を１USBからインストールしようと思うのですが、USBに焼くとそのUSBは今まで通りに使えなくなってしまうのでしょうか...?(データを出し入れしたり)教えてください～！'

'question_link': u'https://www.skyarch.net/blog/?p=6382'
```

Comment: Greatly appreciate for your help but it seems not working yet since it will still show some tags, like <br> <p>. I have include more details in the edit 1 part in the question so as to make it easier to understand/

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting the text of the question wrapper plus the text of all of its descendants:

```
wrapper_selector = "div.mdPstd.mdPstdQstn.sttsRslvd.clrfx div.ptsQes"
item['question_content'] = ''.join([i for i in response.css('{}::text, {} *::text'.format(wrapper_selector)).extract()])
```